# detect JavaFX Tab(Label) on MouseClick

Tags: java, javafx

I am using a **TabPane** in javaFX here is a picture:

[image]

When the user right clicks on the label of the tab a costume contextMenu should appear.But i don't want to add .setContextMenu(...) for each tab instead to use  something like this:

```
tabPane.setOnMouseClicked(m -> {
        if (m.getButton() == MouseButton.SECONDARY) {
            Node pick = m.getPickResult().getIntersectedNode();
            for (Tab tab : getTabs()) {
                if (pick.toString().contains(tab.getText())) {

                    contextMenu.show(tab, m.getScreenX(), m.getScreenY());
                    break;
                }

            }
        }
    });
```

but i can't figure it out how to use **pickResult** for this.

**Why**
.i am doing this is cause the tabs may be hundrends and i don't want to spend so much memory for adding a new ContextMenu for each tab so i use only one with defferent tab every time.

Comment: Why don't you create one context menu and set it (the same one) on all the tabs?

Comment: one static instance can go to multiple tabs?Isn't there a way to now every time which tab(label) i am (right)clicking?

Comment: Well I wouldn't make it static, but I don't see why you can't pass the same instance to multiple tabs. Have you tried it?

Comment: @James_D When the tabs are hundrends then setting in each one a contextMenu(i have a costume class with a lot of vars) it will consume more memory than having only one static ContextMenu.But Isn't there a way to know every time which tab(label) i am (right)clicking? that's my point...

Comment: Well, I don't necessarily see that the memory consumption would be huge, but anyway, I was saying you should use the *same instance of `ContextMenu`* for every tab. (This has nothing at all to do with `static`.)

Comment: @James_D thanks for help.Maybe i should do this..One more question,how does the javaFX understands that i right click on the (label)of tab,how it works is there a costume way to do this?